mac terminal cp multiple directories to multiple directories
very newbie! i can’t figure out, or find an answer to this...
folder1 contains folderA and folderB, which I want to copy (with their content) into folder2, folder3, folder4.
folders 1–4 are children of folderX.
how do i get folderA and folderB into folders 2, 3, 4!? taken all afternoon, haha... i cannot find an answer to this!
have tried, among many other things:
❯ cp -r folder1/folderA folderB /folder2, /folder3, /folder4
❯ cp -r folder1/* folder2, folder3, folder4
❯ cp -r folder1/{folderA folderB} folder2, folder3, folder4
thanks!

Please format your code properly. In a proportional font, it is not easy to see where there are spaces in your code, and how many.

yo i'll do that.  thanks.

You need a cp command per destination:
cp -pr folder1/folder{A,B} folder2/
cp -pr folder1/folder{A,B} folder3/
cp -pr folder1/folder{A,B} folder4/

you can also use a for loop:
for destdir in folder{2,3,4}/
do
    cp -pr folder1/folder{A,B} "$destdir"
done


thank you! this does exactly what i needed! have never used for loops with command line. this is perfect... thanks so much!!
